# Two amazon lambda functions for one lex bot

Tags: python, machine-learning, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

Can we use Two amazon lambda functions for one lex bot if one lambda function in python and other in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can have different Lambda functions for each intent in any language of your choice. So if you are using 10 intents in one Lex bot then you can have 10 different Lambda functions for each of your intent.

However if you are asking for two lambda functions for single intent then it is not possible, but still you can call as many lambda functions from your defined Lambda function.

Below is the code (python) to invoke another lambda function:

```
import boto3
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
a=[1,2,3]
x = {"list" : a}
invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="name_of_other_lambda",
                                       InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                                       Payload=json.dumps(x))
print (invoke_response['Payload'].read())
```

Hope it help.

Comment: How to call another lambda function from defined lambda function @sid8491

Comment: @Allenmiles updated the answer with the code

Answer (score 0):

you can have two lambda functions for two different intents. You cannot have two lambda functions for the same intent